# How can I see the line length available for long mathematical expressions in posting on MO?

Tags: support, mathjax, editing

In typing up a question (or answer) on MO, I try to format a long mathematical expression so that it fits in one line. When I meet with apparent success, as shown in the wysiwyg box underneath the box in which the code is typed, and then post the result, I sometimes find that the expression, which nicely fitted across the box, is only partially visible, and only readable by operating a “slider”, in the published version. If I had known that this is what would happen, I would have rewritten the post, perhaps recasting the long expression into natural, shorter, units that could be distributed across two or more lines.

Thus, how can one tell what the actual available width will be when typing up the text?

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite possible, since it also depends on the local render settings of the reader (e.g. font, zoom, etc.)

Comment: Since you have mentioned slider (scrollbar), my personal experience is that it only appears directly after submitting an edit (and maybe after posting) - and it disappears after a refresh. (Also the point made by Asaf seems rather relevant here. I have seen many users on MO for whom using MO on mobile devices seems important.)

Comment: I agree with the other comments.  Making something look good for me will not necessarily make it look good for other users.  A hint for this situation: constructions that force staying on the same line should rarely be used..